# Wordpress Theme Editor file permissions

Tags: wordpress, file, permissions, themes, editor

At some point I lost the ability to edit my theme files through the WP theme editor because the file is supposedly not writeable (`is_writable()` returns false). When accessing it, the following message is displayed:

> You need to make this file writable before you can save your changes. See Changing File Permissions for more information.

My site is running on my own CentOS 7 server, and I have made sure all the recommended settings for file permissions are in place:

- httpd is running under the apache user
- Files and folders under /var/www/ are owned by apache:apache
- All files permissions are set to 644, and folders to 755
- DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT is not defined
- httpd.conf:

  ```
  <Directory “/var/www/html”>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ```
- /var/www/html/.htaccess:

  ```
  # BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
  # END WordPress
  ```
- Deactivated all plugins
- Tested manually modifying files as apache and that worked as expected (`su -s /bin/bash apache`)

There is something else in my system I can't identify that is stopping me to be able to manage my site appropriately.

System Info:

- CentOS 7
- Apache 2.4.6
- PHP 7.4.16
- MariaDB 10.3.28
- WordPress 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution to my issue:

SELinux was configured to only allow the httpd service read rights to the files. Even though the file permission settings gave the apache user RW rights, the service was being denied.

```
# Check SELinux settings on Wordpress folder
ls -Z /var/www/html/
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 wp-content
```

**object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:** Read Only

**object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:** Read and Write

To configure folder/files you'd like to be able to modify through Wordpress (httpd service):

```
# Configure SELinux to allow Read/Write rights to httpd
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/wp-content -R
```

The example above provides R/W rights to https to the folder /var/www/html/wp-content and all its contents.